# Langlands program vs Shimura-Taniyama-Weil conjecture

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, langlands-conjectures, absolute-galois-group

Edward Frenkel said that "we can  see Langlands program as a generalization of Shimura-Taniyama-Weil conjecture in the case of elliptic curves" 
I hope I'm not distorting his phrase, can someone explain what that means. Lets say that I'm little bit familiar with the ingredients used in both conjectures, Galois representations, elliptic curves,...

Comment: You might look at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55449/in-what-sense-is-taniyama-shimura-the-n-2-case-of-langlands

Comment: The answer given by Matthew Emerton in the above linked question probably wont be surpassed here I think. This question is a duplicate of that one, but since the question was asked on the other site, this question cannot be closed for being a duplicate.

Answer (score 8):

To expand on zeno's answer, a Langlands-type formulation of the modularity conjecture would be:

> (Taniyama-Shimura) $L(E,s)=L(f,s)$

Here $L(E,s)$ is the Hasse-Weil L-function of an elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and $L(f,s)$ is the L-function of a modular form $f$ of weight 2 with integral coefficients. In fact you have a complete correspondence: all elliptic curves (over $\mathbb{Q}$) are modular in that sense, and all newforms (of that type) come from elliptic curves.

A "Langlands generalization" of this result is:

> (Langlands) $L(V,s)=L(\pi,s)$

Here $L(V,s)$ is the Hasse-Weil L-function of *any* algebraic variety $V$ over an arbitrary number field, and $L(\pi,s)$ the L-function of some automorphic form $\pi$ over $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{A})$.

This is a theorem in some cases (other than Taniyama-Shimura), for example abelian varieties over $\mathbb{Q}$, elliptic curves over real quadratic fields and elliptic curves with complex multiplication.

You can further generalize:

> (Langlands) $L(M,s)=L(\pi,s)$

With $L(M,s)$ the L-function of a motive. This of course includes the case above, Artin L-functions (non-abelian class field theory) and all the other Galois representations that should be automorphic ($l$-adic, mod p).

In the other direction, the Langlands conjectures restricted to the the case of an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ predict precisely the same as the Taniyama-Shimura conjecture.

Answer (score 7):

The Taniyama conjecture says that the L-series of an elliptic curve over Q is automorphic (more specifically, arises from a modular form). Langlands conjectures that every L-series arising from algebraic geometry is automorphic (in the sense he defined).